# "Was never heard from ever again since" and should I be using Present Perfect Continuous

Tags: past-simple, present-perfect-progressive

Let's say we have someone of whom we've never heard of ever again since some event.
Do I say:
*"And he was never heard from ever again since"* or *"He has never been heard from ever again since"*.
The latter seems much more correct to me, but the fact that the former is much more widespread keeps throwing me off.

Comment: The present perfect continuous doesn't make any sense here.  The present perfect continuous is something that uses the present participle, like "I have been sleeping."

Answer (score 1):

A simple past negative expression can be followed by 'again' when a past event is considered closed or complete: John Smith went to Borneo in 1853. He entered the jungle on July 25th and was never (or not) heard from again.

A present perfect progressive negative expression can be followed by 'since' when a past event may not be complete (e.g. somebody who vanished may, even only theoretically, reappear): John Smith entered the jungle on May 26th this year; he has not been heard of since. You can use 'ever since' if the elapsed time is notably long, and the event is still considered incomplete.